# Internet via home

Tags: ipad, vpn, internet

On many days, I use an iPad on a network that provides Internet. However this internet network restricts certain websites I can access. Even public VPNs are blocked.

I have an idea. Suppose I could use this network's restricted Internet via WIFI from my iPad (this wifi blacklists certain websites). I connect to my home IP and access the rest of the Internet from there.

**...The problem is I have no idea to do this.**

I heard that you can set up your own VPN host, but I need an option that is free.

I am using a Mac at home with an Apple Airport wifi Tower.

**How can I achieve unrestricted internet from a restricted wifi internet iPad using my home as a gateway?**

Answer (score 1):

What you're wanting to do is called "Virtual Network Computing (VNC)".  Using an iPad makes it more complicated unless you want to purchase an app.  I've used LogMeIn for a while, but that app was about $99.

If you have another Mac at work Apple has an app for $80 called "Remote Desktop".  Open your system preferences on the Mac you want to control and check "Remote Management" then install the app.

For either solution you will need to know your IP at home.  If it's a dynamic IP (often changes) then you'll need a system to let you know when it changes.  Most modern internet connections shouldn't change often or ever though.

Comment: If it costs money, then I can't use that option.

Comment: There are free options going from computer to computer, but having an iPad in the mix is going to make it almost impossible to do for free.

Comment: Maybe someone can suggest hosting a website from the home computer that runs another website?